# UITableView cell change anchor constraint in cellForRowAt

Tags: uitableview, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

In my table view cell I have

```
var myAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    let myAnchor = myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth / 6).isActive = true
```

Then in my table view `cellForRowAt` function I have

```
if indexPath.row == myArray.count - 1 {

        cell.myAnchor!.constant = 0
    }
```

This compiles but crashes with unexpectedly found nil. I want to change the width of the view to 0 for the last row. I can get this done by setting `isHidden = true` but that causes constraint warnings and obviously isn't right. I have also tried setting `isActive = false` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried changing the constraint inside tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: It should still fail because cell.myAnchor is nil.